# How can i navigate to Home Screen in blackberry using qml?

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Hi i have the doubt for the following scenario.

Home Screen -> Second screen (Push )
Second Sreen -> Home Screen (Pop)
Second screen-> Thrid screen (push)
Works correctly.

**Now I need to

Third Screen -> Home Screen**

**home.qml**

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
NavigationPane {
  page {
    Container {
      layout: StackLayout {
      }
      Button {
        text:"Go to Second screen"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**second.qml**

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
page {
  Container {
    layout: StackLayout {
    }
    Button {
      text:"Go to Third screen"
    }
  }
}
```

**third.qml**

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
page {
  Container {
    layout: StackLayout {
    }
    Button {
      text:"Return to Home screen"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
navigationPane.navigateTo(rootPage);
```

**rootPage - It is id of page in Home.qml**

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
NavigationPane {
  page {
    id:rootPage;
    Container {
      layout: StackLayout {
      }
      Button {
        id:btnSecondScreen;
        text:"Go to Second screen"
      }
    }
  }
}
```